# How to extend token_ids to accept more keywords in Boost::wave library

Tags: c++, boost, token, wave

I am working on a syntax highlighting task using Boost/wave library. We get the tokens by dereferencing the lex-token-iterator and then we process these tokens for custom highlighting.

Out of the box, the wave library comes with a cpp lexer which iterates over input C++ files and tokenize keywords. But my work now involves identifying CUDA files as well and tokenize them using the same mechanism.

I can add the CUDA keywords in the token_ids file ([The Token Identifiers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/wave/doc/token_ids.html)), but what would be a more cleaner way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the keywords are part of the lexer, and so the lexer needs to be rebuilt. The token ids are not enough. For a recent example, see [this PR](https://github.com/boostorg/wave/pull/109). If you are willing to treat CUDA keywords as identifiers, that may be a solution (assuming the CUDA code does not appear embedded in C++ as part of a comment or pragma - I am unfamiliar with it).